# Boundary of a Single Point

Tags: real-analysis

If I'm working along the real line which is my metric space, and I have I=(-1,1), and I wand to find the boundary of the boundary of I.  So I found the boundary of I to be {-1, 1}, but then to find the boundary of that, I'm not sure, I don't know whats the boundary of this.  Thanks!

Comment: By definition, the boundary of a set $A$ is $\partial A = \bar A \setminus int A$. So $\partial\{pt\} = \emptyset$.

Comment: @John How is $\{p\}\setminus\emptyset=\emptyset$?

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: Of course it should be $\{p\}\setminus \emptyset = \{p\}$. Thanks.