# Intersection of boundaries

Tags: general-topology

Why the intersection of boundaries isn't the boundary of the intersection? The book I'm reading left it as a exercise to the lector, but I can't find an example .

Comment: Consider two balls in $\Bbb R^2$ of radius 1 and centers at $(0,0)$ and $(\frac{1}{2},0)$ respectively.

Comment: Okey I'll try it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the intervals $[-1, 0], [0, 1] \in \mathbb{R}$. Their intersection is $[-1, 0] \cap [0, 1] = \{0\}$. Their boundaries are $\delta[-1,0]=\{-1,0\}$ and $\delta[0, 1]=\{0, 1\}$. Thus the *intersection of boundaries* is $\{0\}$ and the *boundary of the intersection* is $\varnothing$ (as [a boundary of a singleton is the empty set](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1141337/571466)).